# Should I harvest this cucumber? Additionally, why is this cucumber stem yellow?

Tags: cucumbers

I'm very much a novice gardener, so I'd appreciate any advice! I'm located in BK, New York, Zone 6 (but we've been having some very high temps this summer).

I've always wanted to garden, so I started a container garden this summer. I'm growing cucumbers and peppers, and have just seen my first cucumber germinate! Very exciting.

The variety is Burpless #26, and it should grow to be 10" long (it's been 35 days since I've planted them, and the fruit matures in 70 days). However, I've seen quite a few sites mention that picking earlier is better, as the fruit gets more bitter the longer it sits on the vine. Any thoughts?

Additionally, in another container (same variety), one of the stems of my cucumber plants is turning yellow. The other cucumber plant - the same variety, same pot - is fine, no yellowing stems.

The containers I have are close to 10 gallons large. I have two per pot.

I've included pictures - thanks for your feedback!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Good question & nicely illustrated; Would wait on harvesting it, it may fill out more, so maybe keep an eye on it & if after a while it isnt filling out, then maybe harvest it. They might need a bit more water, they appear to be doing fine re nutrient. Sometimes simply removing the skin improves the flavour, and as long as the cucumbers are growing nicely & arent becoming dry theyre usually ok! They look like theyre doing very well!

The decolouring may be from the plants simply withdrawing energy to put elswhere, or aphids or something could be affecting the tissues.